# What is point of passing rvalue reference to class constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics, rvalue

Ok

So I have a class, MyClass. I would like to construct this class with say a vector of ints. I want to move this vector into the object. The class is not templated.

```
class Myclass {
     public:
     Myclass (std::vector<int> && in) : vec{in} {};
     Myclass (std::vector<int> & in) : vec{in} {};

    private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
    }
```

In my main I have

```
std::vector<int> orig (100);
Myclass A {orig};
std::cout << A.size() << '\n';
```

I want "orig" to be empty after moving it into "A". That does not happen in either of the options above.
Even if I do

```
    std::vector<int> orig (100);
    Myclass A {std::move(orig)};
    std::cout << A.size() << '\n';  // still prints 100
```

It looks like I can achieve it via

```
 Myclass (std::vector<int> && in) : vec{std::move(in)} {};   // (1)
```

OR

```
 Myclass (std::vector<int> & in) : vec{std::move(in)} {};    // (2)
```

OR

```
Myclass (std::vector<int> && in) : vec{std::forward<std::vector<int>(in)} {};    // (3)
```

My question is why does (1) appear to behave exactly like (2)?

Comment: Note that you can unify both constructors into a single `Myclass(std::vector<int> in) : vec{std::move(in)} { }` constructor. The caller can decide whether to move-construct or copy-construct the temporary vector based on whether they need to retain a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to remember about references, rvalue and lvalue, is that they are lvalues.  That means if you have a reference to a thing, that reference is an lvalue and you need `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue so it can be moved.

The real difference between `Myclass (std::vector<int> && in)` and `Myclass (std::vector<int> & in)` is that with the first you have to use

```
Myclass A {std::move(orig)};
// or
Myclass A {std::vector(100)};
```

and cant pass an lvalue to it, where as with second you can only uses

```
Myclass A {orig};
```

as it wont let you pass an rvalue to it.

---

Also note that constructor 3 is "incorrect".  You should only use `std::forward` when you have a forwarding reference.  `std::vector<int> && in` is a rvalue reference, not a forwarding one so you should use `std::move` instead.  To use forward correctly you'd need a template constructor like

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<
                                       std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, 
                                       std::vector<int>>, bool> = true>
Myclass (T&& in) : vec{std::forward<T>(in)} {};
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I had only seen the forward with templates which is why I explicitly mentioned that my class wasn't templated....although it seemed to "work" but maybe it didn't. You second example, making the vector on the fly and passing it to the constructor is a good reason for having the rvalue ref version. I hadn't thought of that! I was trying to think why one might be useful if it didn't actually "forward" the rvalue ref.

Comment: @TCD It will "work" in this case, but that is more happy coincidence.  Just having the class be a template is not enough.  If you have `template <typename T> struct foo{ foo(T&&); };` that `foo(T&&)` is **not** a forwarding reference, it is an rvalue reference.  You **only** get a forwarding reference when you have something like `/*template <typename T>*/ struct foo{ template <typename T> foo(T&&); };`